# How do I distinguish PHP from Silex and Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, config, silex

So, first of all, I'm really kinda new to programming in general (I'm a CS student interning).

My task is to strip away some Symfony2 and Silex from a `config.php` file. Apparently these two frameworks are not needed for our website to work (they used to be required but now we're making some changes in terms of how the site is sitting on the server).

The biggest problem is that I just started learning PHP. Most of my past work has been in Java. I honestly haven't even used a framework before so I really don't even know exactly what Symfony2 and Silex are responsible for.

Are there any shortcuts I can take (things to look for) or resources to help me?

I just gotta delete anything Silex/Symfony related. I feel like learning all about the frameworks would be overly time consuming. What do you guys think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove a framework dependency from existing working project - this may lead to rewrite whole site from the ground. There is no simple answer to question "how to remove framework?".

> I really don't even know exactly what Symfony2 and Silex are responsible for

This is actually most important question here. And there is no general answer, it depends on your project. This could be routing, db abstraction, from handling and validation, error handling, security and etc. So your have to identify it by yourself digging the code. And for that you have to learn something about the framework (Silex), otherwise you can't recognize if this or that part of project's code are related to the framework.

Next step: if you want delete anything Silex/Symfony2 related, you will have to rewrite (replace) deleted functionality by your own implementations. It would be hard for you as a newcomer in PHP world. In general this is not a good idea to write your own implementation of all these things which already done in the framework.

If your boss asked your to remove Silex/Symfony2 and you can't change it - you are in hard situation.

If it's your own initiative to remove Silex/Symfony2 - I would recommend first identify scope of work and measure all advantages/disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the includes. Do they have Silex or Symfony in the path names? If so, delete them.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of config file is it exactly? 
If it's plain PHP & you just have to get rid of some functions, it should be OK : you could open your file in Eclipse / whatever IDE you use & check with ctrl+clic if the functions goes in a Symfony bundle...

Can you give us some examples?